# How to structure HTML navbar for both mobile and desktop screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, dry

I have made two HTML navbars (one for desktop screens and another for mobile screens) and I want to have only one HTML navbar and use CSS to style for both screen sizes since I believe it's not a good idea to repeat your code.

The thing is I have never done this thing before and most sample examples I found are using CSS frameworks. How should I approach this issue?

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```js
function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "250px";
      }

function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "0";
      }
```

```css
.navbar {
        background-color: white;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .main-nav {
        display: none;
      }

      .navbar-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 20px;
        font-size: 19px;
      }

      .nav-mobile {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: white;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 80px;
      }

      .nav-mobile a {
        display: block;
      }

      .nav-mobile .closebutton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 5px;
        font-size: 56px;
      }

      .bar1,
      .bar2,
      .bar3 {
        width: 25px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 6px 0;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .main-nav {
          display: flex;
          margin-right: 30px;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        .navbar-toggle {
          display: none;
        }

        .navbar {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
        }
      }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
      <div class="logo-position">
        <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">About</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="nav-links">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar for mobile -->
    <div id="sidenav" class="nav-mobile">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebutton" onclick="closeNav()"
        >&times;</a
      >
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-toggle" onclick="openNav()">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: check this link "https://www.w3jar.com/editor/?fname=css-responsive-navigation-menu"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use media queries to make anything responsive. You are right about repetitive code, it's not good in any way. You can use `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {}` to target mobile devices and show/hide elements in desktop/mobile.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo-position">
        <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-toggle" onclick="openNav()">  <!--HIDE IN DESKTOP-->
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="main-nav"> <!--HIDE IN MOBILE-->
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-links">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Following a tutorial is a good start. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp